# URL adress and pagination. React.Js, Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, request, material-ui

I have a functional component-page of my website, inside one of page i have a table and this table getting data on API. For more comfortability table have pagination. I'm use ready solution pagination from Material-UI. My pagination work fine, when i change page, data in my table is changing, but the URL address does not. I want to be able send URL with some param(like GET request or something), which display specific page of table.

I tried to use two solutions but both don't work as I need

First solution with Router. I'm not sure if this is what I need, because pages of table does not have individual pages, table just getting data from API and then separate them on pages. Besides, this solution create links for pages, but not change URL when I going through the pages

```
import React from 'react'
import { MemoryRouter, Route } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';
import PaginationItem from '@material-ui/lab/PaginationItem';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        display: 'flex'
    },
    pagination: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginBottom: '2%'
    }
}));

function Paginations({ totalPages, setCurrentPage }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const paginationHandler = (event, value) => {
        setCurrentPage(value);
    };

    return (
        <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/log']} initialIndex={0}>
            <Route>
                {({ location }) => {
                    const query = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
                    const page = parseInt(query.get('page') || '1', 10);
                    return (
                        <div className={classes.root}>
                            <Pagination
                                className={classes.pagination}
                                page={page}
                                count={totalPages}
                                onChange={paginationHandler}
                                renderItem={(item) => (
                                    <PaginationItem
                                        component={Link}
                                        to={`/log${item.page === 1 ? '' : `?page=${item.page}`}`}
                                        {...item}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                }}
            </Route>
        </MemoryRouter >
    )
}

export default Paginations;
```

Second Solution: It's way too change pages in table but not is changing URL

```
import React from 'react'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Pagination from '@material-ui/lab/Pagination';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '& > *': {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        display: 'flex'
    },
    pagination: {
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginBottom: '2%'
    }
}));

function Paginations({ totalPages, setCurrentPage }) {
    const classes = useStyles();

    const paginationHandler = (event, value) => {
        setCurrentPage(value);
    };

    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Pagination count={totalPages} className={classes.pagination} onChange={paginationHandler} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Paginations;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't edit your code, but outline a principle of how to achieve your solution.

You need to keep your pagination state in your component. Then, You need to do 2 things:

- When you change the page, set your query parameter in the url to this
  page number. Also keep that page number in your state, as your
  pagination is a controlled component now.
- When you initially load the component, get a page number from the url
  params and set your pagination state with this information. So table can be displayed on that page.

Here is the simplest working example:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const App = (props: Object) => {
const history = useHistory();

let search = window.location.search;
let params = new URLSearchParams(search);

const [page, setPage] = React.useState<number>( parseInt("" + params.get('page')))

const paginate = (n: number) => {
    setPage(n)
    history.push({
        pathname: '/',
        search: '?page=' + n
      })
}

return (
<div >
    <div onClick={()=>paginate(1)} style={page===1 ? {fontSize:30} : {}}>1</div>
    <div onClick={()=>paginate(2)} style={page===2 ? {fontSize:30} : {}}>2</div>
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-pagination-7do5s

Alternatively, search, params and page variables could be calculated and set only after the first mount, in React.useEffect hook. Up to you.

Please note this is a typescript file, if you're only using Javascript, remove  type.
Also I am using react-router-dom to change query parameter in the url. This will only work, when this component is wrapped by Router.

my index.tsx file:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <Router>
        <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It work, but in my case state must have default value, so i use
const [page, setPage] = useState( parseInt("" + params.get('page')) || 1)

Answer (score 0):

For people who are looking at this solution, after the react-router upgrade we  use `navigate("/page")` after importing `useNavigate` instead of `history.push()`